# How to add multiple SubElement using lxml.etree? (python)

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

I would like to use lxml.etree to write out several SubElements under one primary tags with several subtags.

This is the code that I'm using to write out my tags.

```
def create_SubElement(_parent, _tag, attrib={}, _text=None, nsmap=None, **_extra):
    result = ET.SubElement(_parent, _tag, attrib, nsmap, **_extra)
    result.text = _text
    return result
```

This is my code that has multiple p_tags.

```
for key_products in primary_details:
    try:
        if 'Products' in key_products.h3.text:
            for p_tag in key_products.find_all('p'):
                products = create_SubElement(root, 'Products', _text=p_tag.text)

      except:
            continue

print (ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

The code above currently produces this output:

```
'<root>\n 
    <Products>product name 1 </Products>\n  
    <Products>product name 2 </Products>\n  
    <Products>product name 3 </Products>\n  
    <Products>product name 4 </Products>\n  
    <Products>product name 5 </Products>\n  
</root>\n'
```

The desired output would be something like this:

```
'<root>\n 
    <Products>
      <ProductName>product name 1 </ProductName>\n  
      <ProductName>product name 2 </ProductName>\n  
      <ProductName>product name 3 </ProductName>\n  
      <ProductName>product name 4 </ProductName>\n  
      <ProductName>product name 5 </ProductName>\n 
   <Products> 
</root>\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create `Products` element once and create multiple `ProductName` elements using `Products` as parent, something like this :

```
....
if 'Products' in key_products.h3.text:
    # create Products element once:
    products = create_SubElement(root, 'Products')
    for p_tag in key_products.find_all('p'):
        # create ProductName element using Products as parent
        productName = create_SubElement(products, 'ProductName', _text=p_tag.text)
```

Comment: How would I handle Products, which have no ProductNames?  I tried creating a _text=NULL value when p_tag is <= 0, but that didn't work.  I'm trying to create a tag that read <Product> NULL </Products>.